# Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {“method”:“css selector”,“selector”:“.syllable”}

Tags: python, html, selenium

Я хочу достать текст из html кода сайта с помощью библиотеки selenium на python. Я пробовал поиск по имени класса, поиск по xpath, но ничего не получилось. Мой код ниже.

```py
driver.find_element_by_class_name('syllable')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div')
```

html код сайта(Мне нужно получить gi):

```html
<div class="round">
<div class="syllable">gi</div>
</div>
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так:

```py
element.get_attribute('textContent')
```